# Count rows in mysql database where timestamp within X interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count the rows in a table in my database that were inserted within X hours or X days.  I have tried repeatedly but I keep getting empty set responses.

The start_stamp column in my table is formatted like this: 2013-08-07 18:18:37

I have tried many variations on:
select * from mytable where start_stamp = now() interval -1 day;

But all to no avail.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem with your query?  What is the type of `start_stamp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than selecting rows where `start_stamp` is *equal* to `now() - 1day`, you need rows where it is *greater than or equal to* that range. Additionally, your syntax is a little off. MySQL's date arithmetic uses `column_value - INTERVAL <number> <period>`, so you need:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_new_rows
FROM mytable
WHERE start_stamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Likewise to get *n* hours ago, use `INTERVAL n HOUR`

```
# Within 3 hours...
WHERE start_stamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR
```

The syntax for date interval arithmetic is described [in a small paragraph beneath the `DATE_ADD()` function reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) in the official MySQL documentation.

Comment: An index on the `start_stamp` column will help performance with this query.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a some examples...

All entries within the past 6 hours:

```
select * from mytable where start_stamp >= now() - interval 6 hour;
```

All entries within the past 2 days:

```
select * from mytable where start_stamp >= now() - interval 2 day;
```

All entries within the past 2 1/2 days:

```
select * from mytable where start_stamp >= now() - interval 2 day - interval 12 hour;
```